# Distinctive property of the primes 17 and 19?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, prime-numbers

Consider the question whether it is true that a prime number $p$ divides
$1^1+2^2+3^3+....+(p-1)^{p-1}$ if and only if $p \in \{17,19\}$.

For the obvious heuristic reasons, for large $n$ one would expect there
to be roughly $\ln(\ln(n))$ such primes $p < n$, however it seems that presently
no examples other than 17 and 19 are known.

Is there a more efficient way of looking for examples than the brute force method of
testing the primes one-by-one?

Comment: See the FAQ's section on open problems. Also, what evidence is there that this is true? If you pick a random number mod each prime, this should be $0$ infinitely often, but the number of times you pick $0$ among the first $n$ primes will grow as $\log \log n$. So, if you see two examples among the first $1000$ or $10^6$, this is still not much evidence that there is anything special about those two examples, and that there aren't infinitely many examples.

Comment: Another interesting paper is about the residues of $n^n$ mod $p$ for $n=1,2,\ldots ,p-1$, here: www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/19-2/somer.pdf‎

Comment: @Gjergji, that depends on the country where you are.

Comment: So it seems likely that there are more examples but a search would take a while (if successful, longer if not). To check any particular prime is not hard. I see no reason to expect shortcuts.

Comment: The only shortcut I can think of would be to compute modulo products of primes, thus checking ranges of primes at once.

Comment: Is there ANY property of primes where for the obvious heuristic reasons one would expect there to be roughly ln(ln(n)) such primes p<n, and for which there is a proof that there are infinitely many such primes?

Comment: This (very early!) paper of Soundararajan http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1207502 shows that there are $O( \log x / (\log \log x)^2)$ primes of the form $1^1 + \ldots + n^n$ less than $x$.  This doesn't directly help with the problem though...

Comment: I was interested in the determinant (mod $p$) and the trace (mod $p$) of a matrix defined as follows :-
For each prime $p$, define a $(p-1)*(p-1)$ integer matrix $M^{p}$ as $M^{p}_{ij} \equiv i^{j}$ (mod $p$), $0<i<p, 0<j<p$. 
I was surprised to see that the trace was 0 (mod $p$) only for 17 and 19 in the first 3000 primes and thus I thought of posting this question. (I know that 3000 is very small number and one should not make any blind conjecture based on only 3000 evidences).

Comment: @Mihir, you should have explained this in your question, rather than asking people to prove something.

Comment: @Fernando: I am extremely sorry for that, but now the question has been edited by Stefan Kohl and it has been asked in an appropriate language. 

Comment: I tested the technique of computing modulo products of consecutive primes in the interval $p \in [10^5,10^5+10^4]$ (using Pari/GP). The naïve test takes approximately 40 seconds. Computing modulo products $P=p_1 \ldots p_n$ and optimizing $n$ rouhgly halves down the computing time.

Comment: @André I was wondering the same thing - this is very reminiscent of questions about Wilson primes, for instance, or other questions about whether a given sum of factors is divisible by $p$; naively any such question will lead to roughly log log n solutions and I can't think of any offhand that are satisfied by some but not all primes.  See math.stackexchange.com/questions/337053/second-part-of-the-factorial-sum-divisibility-question/ for another example...

Comment: @André Now asked over on math.SE : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405944/an-infinitude-of-congruence-condition-primes

Comment: I tested up to 47,537,000 with no new solutions, in C with GMP.  This took several weeks on a multi-core processor, suggesting that the estimate by "none" is a bit optimistic.  The fastest method I found involved working modulo a product of primes that was just below either 128 or 256 bits (depending on the size range).  Anyway, I'm giving up on this particular computation.

Answer (score 1):

exp(exp(3)) is about 5e8 and testing the primes up to that is probably feasible with a few days of computer abuse.  I tested up to 1e5 in 6 minutes with a trivial, single-threaded Haskell script (no more p's found).  I don't see any particular reason to think there are no more p's though.  It would surprise me if searching didn't turn up another p.

Comment: Testing up to $N$ takes time proportional to $N^2$ (the sum mod $p$
is a sum of $p$ terms, each of which takes about $\log p$ operations
mod $p$, and there are $N/\log N$ terms to try.  So going from $10^5$
to $5 \cdot 10^8$ would multiply the computing time not by $500$ but
by about a quarter-million, unless there's some clever speedup I'm
not seeing to a smaller power than $N^2$.

Comment: One passably clever speedup would memoize mod p the results of $m^m$ and $n^n$ to aid in calculating $mn^{mn}$, but I don't see it reducing the exponent on the runtime.  Gerhard "Has Not Thought It Through" Paseman, 2013.05.27

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I can't post them, sorry.  To follow up the above: Prof. Elkies is of course right about the $O(n^2)\,$ complexity of the basic algorithm, but it should be possible to get large constant-factor speedups with better implementation:

- First of all there's probably 10x-50x available just by rewriting the program in C using the naive algorithm, and running on a multi-core processor, depending on available hardware.  Let's say 25x on an 8-core AMD processor.
- There might be another 2x(?) using Montgomery's representation (from cryptography) to get rid of most of the integer division operations in the modular exponentials.  Actually maybe a lot more than 2x.
- Finally, combining the above (I'm less sure of this) it might be possible to run on a graphics accelerator giving 100x or more.

Assuming 50x (perhaps using two or three computers) that would give 250000*6 minutes / 1440 minutes/day = about 3 weeks, which is above my guess of a "few days" but I think still feasible if someone was really interested.  I'm surprised by how many upvotes this thread got.

Comment: See also http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3436 for ideas about possible mathematical speedups.